# Motherboard's website doesn't have all of the latest drivers & doesn't explain what ones I should install

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I've literally just re-installed my operating system because it kept BSODing for some reason and I'm trying to find the 100% latest drivers for my motherboard.

My motherboard is an ASRock X79 Extreme6, The drivers for Windows 7 64bit can be found: http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/X79%20Extreme6/?cat=Download&os=Win764

The LAN Driver for example is version 14.8.4.1, I managed to find the latest driver which is for chipset 57781 and the version is: 15.6.0.10. I also downloaded the Realtek drivers from their website so instead of installing

The drivers that I am unsure about are:

- INF driver ver: 9.4.0.1017
- Intel Management Engine driver ver: 8.1.40.1416
- ASMedia SATA3 Driver ver: 1.2.8
- Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver and utility ver: 12.7.0.1036
- Intel Rapid Storage Technology enterprise driver and utility ver: 3.5.0.1101
- TI USB 3.0 driver ver: 1.12.9
- ASMedia USB 3.0 driver ver: 1.10.1.0

I have no idea what drivers from above I need to install and where to find the latest of each driver... I was told recently that I shouldn't install TI USB 3.0 drivers and ASMedia USB 3.0 drivers side by side, so which one should I install?

Comment: Install the drivers on the OEM's website.  Unless there is a specific reason you need the "later" driver which specifically fixes something that isn't work for you it shouldn't be installed.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a better bet to stick with the drivers from the motherboard manufacturer.  These drivers are known to work with your board's exact configuration (since most things that require drivers can be at least mildly customized.)  And most BSOD issues are hardware related (thermal/mechanical/electrical.)  If a driver were the cause of BSOD issues, the MoBo maker would be the place to get a fixed driver in any case.

The first place you should start with any BSOD is a memory scan (MemTest86+ or equivalent).  Then move on to temp monitoring of CPU and graphics card.  Next, check for mechanical/electrical issues (a sagging graphics card or other loose cards, bare wires, etc.)  I once had a recurring BSOD that I narrowed down to an incompatible SATA BD-ROM drive.

Comment: CPU and GPU temperatures are fine even under heavy load, Memory was fine under MemTest86+ and Windows Memory Diagnostics, I've checked for lose cables, cards and bare wires but still can't find the source of the issue :(

Comment: You'll need to monitor temps for a long time.  If it is a thermal expansion issue the temps will go from fine to emergency shutdown in fractions of a second.

Answer (score 0):

I would also check the power. If your power fluctuates too much it can cause all kinds of weird, almost untraceable issues as this can change the bit state in the RAM, CPU, and even corrupt data on your hard drive as the read and write voltages are not quite what they should be.

Check your motherboard's website for utilities that can check the voltages. There are also third-party tools that can do the same such as Speed Fan.

http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: BSOD was mentioned, which I responded to in general. I will edit out that part. As it is the user should check the power as that can definitely cause weird, almost un traceable problems as the voltages fluctuate all over the place.